# Are there other film collections like the Criterion collection?

Tags: film-industry

Are there other curated film collections like the Criterion collection?

Answer (score 5):

If by curated, you mean general releases overseen by a group: **Yes. Many**

If you mean in terms of overall quality for film-buffs and enthusiasts, the short is answer: **No**.

Longer answer: There are distribution companies like [Anchor Bay](http://www.anchorbayentertainment.com/Entertainment.aspx), [Blue Underground](http://www.blue-underground.com/), and the [Kino Collection](http://www.kinolorber.com/video-store.php) (who made a great name for themselves in releasing well-received foreign releases and art-house films by such unique filmmakers as the Quay Brothers and Jan Švankmajer) as well as studio-mandated "classic-treatments" like [Infinifilm](http://www.infinifilm.com/), [Sony Classics](http://www.sonyclassics.com/), [Paramount Vantage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paramount_Vantage) (now nearly defunct), and others. While Anchor Bay and Blue Underground provide quality versions of more underground and genre films, nothing compares to the scope of the Criterion Collection and their exemplary releases with the best possible film-to-disc transfers and extras that include cast and crew. The Criterion Collection has set the bar higher than any other single distributor can match, having begun to release [laserdisc](http://www.criterion.com/help#q1) widescreen editions of movies *with extras* (including audio commentaries) in 1984. It should be noted that the Criterion Collection has been partners with [Janus Films](http://www.janusfilms.com/) for *many* of their releases.

Comment: @jlmcdonald makes a couple other good points. Turner Classic Movies gets the rights to show films on their channel much more often than they get right to *release* films under their name. More than a competitor to selling Criterion-level DVD's or Blurays, TCM is the channel to watch if you are a fan of Criterion Collection-type movies. Especially because TCM shows the movies uncut and in their original aspect ratio.

Answer (score 3):

There's the Kino collection [here](http://www.kinolorber.com/about.php) and Eureka's 'Masters of Cinema' collection [here](http://www.eurekavideo.co.uk/moc).

[Roskino](http://roskino.org/about?lang=en) provides a like-minded option for Russian and Soviet-era film. I'm sure there are others for many other countries.

The Turner Classic Movies library might also be considered something akin to the Criterion Collection, although your mileage may vary.